# Object reference not set to an instance of an object - Model Binding

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have read [Object reference not set to an instance of an object.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8206810/object-reference-not-set-to-an-instance-of-an-object) and [What does “Object reference not set to an instance of an object” mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/779091/what-does-object-reference-not-set-to-an-instance-of-an-object-mean) posts but still not able to get help because *my case is different.*

**Simple Code**

```
<script>
   var PatientId;
   var DoctorId;

   if(isPatient && @Model.Patient != null) {
        PatientId = @Model.Patient.Id;
        DoctorId = userConnection.User.Id;
   } else if(!isPatient && @Model.Doctor != null) {
        DoctorId = @Model.Doctor.Id; // Right here I get ERROR
        PatientId = userConnection.User.Id;
   }
</script
```

**Error**

```
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

In my case either `@Model.Patient` or `@Model.Doctor` will be `null`.

Right now I know that `@Model.Doctor` is `null`, but I am already checking its `null` condition above. How to cater this problem ?

Comment: Why the double && &&?  <br>  } else if(!isPatient &&  && @Model.Doctor != null) {

Comment: @IvayloStoev Sorry its typo. It not in original code.

Comment: On which line you are getting the exception? How isPatient is initialized?

Comment: From backend Patient is initialized while doctor is null.

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya DoctorId = @Model.Doctor.Id; // Right here I get ERROR

Comment: Model.Doctor is null. As far as i can see you are generating javascript code in the view from the model. This code is not getting executed so you never check if Model.Doctor is null

Comment: @IvayloStoev exactly. So is there any work around to this ?

Comment: You can not mix javascript (executed on the client) and c# code executed on the server) like that. You can use the Model to help you generate javascript code but not check against the model like that.

Comment: Not sure why this was marked as duplicate. I understand that the Exception is the same as the other questions but the context is different here. Solution of this particular case would be different based on the given situation.

Comment: @Junaid you need to create server side variables at the top of the view and assign their values to the JS variables in your script block. Script block should be after the variable declaration. Then you check the values of the JS variables to have your logic further. @{

    var patientId = Model.Patient != null ? Model.Patient.Id : 0;
    var doctorId = Model.Doctor != null ? Model.Doctor.Id : 0;
}<script>
   var PatientId = @patientId;
    var DoctorId = @doctorId;

    alert(PatientId);
    alert(DoctorId);
</script>

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya This one worked. Thanks