# "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" error with Durable Entity

Tags: c#, azure, azure-durable-functions

I want to implement an entity class in my Azure Durable Function. This should store a list of codes. Unfortunately, I get the following error when executing the Set method:

System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'.

Here is the code:

```
[JsonObject(MemberSerialization = MemberSerialization.OptIn)]
public class OrchestrationStatus
{
    [JsonProperty("orchestrationStatus")]
    public List<string> orchestrationStatus { get; set; } = new List<string>();

    public Task Set(string code) 
    {
        this.orchestrationStatus.Add(code);

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    public Task<List<string>> Get() 
    {
        return Task.FromResult(this.orchestrationStatus);
    }

    [FunctionName(nameof(OrchestrationStatus))]
    public static Task Run([EntityTrigger] IDurableEntityContext ctx)
        => ctx.DispatchAsync<OrchestrationStatus>();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve the problem by removing breakpoints from the entity class. Apparently, there is a bug with the debugger!

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to access a member of a class instance using a null reference then you will get a [System.NullReferenceException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.nullreferenceexception%28loband%29.aspx) : ***Object reference not set to an instance of an object*.**

Please check the below links for more information:

.[Object reference not set to an instance of an object | SO THREAD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8206810/object-reference-not-set-to-an-instance-of-an-object)

.[What does “Object reference not set to an instance of an object” mean| SO THREAD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/779091/what-does-object-reference-not-set-to-an-instance-of-an-object-mean) .

.[Durable Entities in .NET  .](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-dotnet-entities)& [To create Durable function |MS DOC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-create-first-csharp?pivots=code-editor-vscode) .